# Grails - rendering UUID to JSON

Tags: json, grails

I'm using UUID as generator for my domain classes. When I render domain objects as JSON, the id looks like the following:

```
"id":{"class":"java.util.UUID","leastSignificantBits":-7570618374586820490,"mostSignificantBits":126481566314875615}
```

Instead, I want it to look as simple as,

```
"id":"01c15a50-7ed5-4adf-96ef-c2b2fcb51876"
```

which is how it looks like when I render the domain objects to XML. How do I make it work this way?

Answer (score 0):

It may help if you post your domain class, but my assumption is it's something like the following:

```
class MyDomain {
  UUID id = UUID.randomUUID()
}
```

Unless you explicitly need to keep it as a UUID, I imagine this will render the JSON as you're expecting:

```
class MyDomain {
  String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I required the **UUID** class so that ORM would work between Grails and Oracle, I couldn't just make the `id` field a String.

So instead, I used a very basic JsonRenderer to override the default (troublsome) JSON rendering of a UUID object.

```
@CompileStatic
class UuidJsonRenderer extends DefaultJsonRenderer<java.util.UUID> {
    UuidJsonRenderer() {
        super(java.util.UUID)
    }
    void renderJson(java.util.UUID object, RenderContext context) {
        super.renderJson(object.toString(), context)
    }
}
```

And plugged it in as a bean the following in **resources.groovy**:

```
beans = {
    // Custom Renderers
    uuidJsonRenderer(UuidJsonRenderer)
}
```

(I think you could probably annotate the renderer and have an annotation processor do this part automatically, if that's your pleasure.)