# Post request body doesn't resolve variables

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have simple test using rest-assured as below.
Case1: If I pass json string as below, it works fine.

```
@Test
    public void dummyTest throws Exception() {

       String newUserEmail = "postOrder" + UUID.randomUUID() + "@gmail.com";
       String json = "{\n" +
                 "    \"name\": \"Marisa\",\n" +
                "    \"birthday\": \"1997-10-06\",\n" +
                "    \"title\": \"Dr.\",\n" +
                "    \"email\": \"postOrder26@gmail.com\",\n" +
                "  },\n" 
       given()
                .baseUri("my_request_url")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .body(json)
                .when()
                .post()
                .then()
                .log().all();
}
```

Above returns 200 response.

---

But If I write my test as below , passing email as variable, returns 500

```
 @Test
    public void dummyTest throws Exception() {

       String newUserEmail = "postOrder" + UUID.randomUUID() + "@gmail.com";
       String json = "{\n" +
                 "    \"name\": \"Marisa\",\n" +
                "    \"birthday\": \"1997-10-06\",\n" +
                "    \"title\": \"Dr.\",\n" +
               "    \"email\": \""+newUserEmail+"\",\n" +
               "  },\n" 
       given()
                .baseUri("my_request_url")
                 .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .body(json)
                .when()
                .post()
                .then()
                .log().all();
}
```

---

I get 500 error response

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Mon, 16 Aug 2021 17:05:36 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 871dedfc10f4428aa2412b6f788b791a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: ZRH50-C1
X-Amz-Cf-Id: xGkO8cJGV0Pq7wAx71YyglWzQNdZzooohqZLZBHkC54iZgiNhGmpEA==

<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
    <style>
            /* Copyright (c) 2010, Yahoo! Inc. All rights reserved. Code licensed under the BSD License: https://yuilibrary.com/license/ */
            html{color:#000;background:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:text-top;}sub{vertical-align:text-bottom;}input,textarea,select{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}legend{color:#000;}
            html { background: #eee; padding: 10px }
            img { border: 0; }
            #sf-resetcontent { width:970px; margin:0 auto; }
                            body { background-color: #fff; color: #222; font: 16px/1.5 -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif; margin: 0; }
                .container { margin: 30px; max-width: 600px; }
                h1 { color: #dc3545; font-size: 24px; }
        </style>
  </head>
  <body>
```

can anyone please suggest me, how to solve this 500 error

Comment: Sorry, your code sample is full of bug, so I can't determine which one this the cause. Please correct them. E.g  `public void dummyTest throws Exception` --> missing `()` after method name.  No `;` at the end of statement.

Comment: Is there an error logged on the server side?

Answer (score -1):

Your question might be answered here:
[Grails - rendering UUID to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330196/grails-rendering-uuid-to-json)

The UUID data type is not a string, but a bitmapped number, as such it needs conversion to a string before concatenation. The .toString() function should fix the second block. I'm not sure of the specifics of the "+" operator in json, but I believe the type casting goes with C.

Comment: String concatenation will automatically call `toString`.